# Как подключиться к API из PHPMyAdmin таблицы?

Tags: api, phpmyadmin

Есть таблица в PHPMyAdmin, там лежит текст для обработки.

Нужно его отправить в openai.com.
Как подключиться к API из PHPMyAdmin таблицы? Как передать данные и записать ответ из API? Там есть какой-то коннектор для API?

Я использовал гугл таблицы, но там лимиты на данные. Нужно на своем сервере делать в своих таблицах.

Или может какой-то табличный процессор с АПИ-коннектором можно установить себе на хостинг?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть возможно через curl из PHPMyAdmin

```
// API-ключ для доступа к OpenAI
$api_key = 'your_api_key_here';

// Текст для обработки, полученный из таблицы в PHPMyAdmin
$text = $row['text'];

// Формируем заголовки запроса
$headers = array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: Bearer '.$api_key
);

// Формируем тело запроса
$data = array(
    'prompt' => $text,
    'temperature' => 0.5,
    'max_tokens' => 50
);

// Инициализируем cURL-сессию
$curl = curl_init();

// Устанавливаем параметры запроса
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/davinci-codex/completions',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($data),
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers
));

// Отправляем запрос на API OpenAI
$response = curl_exec($curl);

// Обрабатываем ответ
if ($response === false) {
    // Обработка ошибок
    echo 'Ошибка при запросе к API OpenAI: '.curl_error($curl);
} else {
    $result = json_decode($response, true);
    // Обработка результата
    // ...
}

// Закрываем cURL-сессию
curl_close($curl);
```

Код отправляет POST-запрос на API OpenAI с текстом для обработки, полученным из таблицы в PHPMyAdmin. API возвращает ответ в формате JSON, выводится на экран.
your_api_key_here = API-ключ  openai.com.

Comment: Где данный код должен быть указан в PHPMyAdmin? И как получить `$text = $row['text'];` силами PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: $text = $row['text'] в PHP, надо выполнить запрос к базе данных, в котором будет выбрана нужная строка из таблицы с текстом
я скинул пример кода, который надо довести до ума, я думаю вы сможете это сделать